# Getting the error message "Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -15"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having the following problem:

I execute a DAG in Airflow that scrape weather information, based on a array of cities. When the DAG executes with more then 1 city, everything works fine. But, when I need to scrape from only one city, I get a error from selenium, with the message **Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -15**. I looked all over, but couldnt find what this code stands for, and revised the code for any logic problem, but everything is fine. Here is my function that starts a driver:

```
def start_driver():
    localdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {'download.default_directory': localdir}
    os.system('sudo chmod 777 {}'.format(localdir))
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
        "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled":False,"name":"Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
        "download": {
        "prompt_for_download": False,
        "default_directory"  : localdir
        }
    })
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

    # add acceptInsecureCerts
    capabilities = options.to_capabilities()
    capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True

    root_path = '/home/airflow/airflow/dags'

    exe_path = os.path.join(root_path, 'chromedriver')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(exe_path, chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)

    return driver
```

And here is the complete error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/airflow/dags/scripts/extract.py", line 625, in execute_extraction_task
    start_crawler(city_list, cursor)
  File "/home/airflow/airflow/dags/scripts/extract.py", line 231, in start_crawler
    driver = start_driver()
  File "/home/airflow/airflow/dags/scripts/extract.py", line 155, in start_driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(exe_path, chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 109, in assert_process_still_running
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -15
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First up, here's a few options that can help:

```py
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
```

Next up, you're using an older version of `selenium`, which doesn't include important updates. Even though you didn't directly specify which version you're using, I can see that you're still passing `executable_path` via `webdriver.Chrome()`, but that was moved to `Service()` in the most-recent version. `selenium` also includes a Driver Manager in the most-recent version to guarantee that you have the correct driver. Here's a code sample:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

If the correct driver isn't found on your system PATH, Selenium Manager will automatically download it.

Here's how to specify an `executable_path` in the new `selenium` `4.10.0` with the `service` arg:

```py
service = Service(executable_path='./chromedriver')
```

(Specifying an `executable_path` is optional in the latest `selenium` version.)

Comment: Thank you! I did not updated the selenium version yet. But, I did added both options that you sugested, and the correct path. Now I'm getting the following error: `('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`